# Magento Field label containing html characters

Tags: html, magento

I am having issues with displaying html in a form element's label.

Here is the code:

```
$fieldset->addField($season->getId()."_".$question->getId(), 'checkboxes', array(
                    'name'  => $season->getId()."_".$question->getId(),
                    'label' => $question->question,
                    'title' => $question->question,
                    'class' => 'season-questions '.$season->getId(),
                    'values' => $options,
                    'value' => ''
                ));
```

Currently $question->question can sometimes contain html characters such as

```
<p><strong>text</strong></p>
```

which is just rendered as a string when displayed in browser.

How do I get the html to display properly? I have tried:

```
getEscapedValue()
```

and

```
toHtml()
```

to no avail.

Comment: what is `$question->question` ?

Comment: It is of type string

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove html elements, you can use `strip_tags ()`. So try this.

```
$fieldset->addField($season->getId()."_".$question->getId(), 'checkboxes', array(
     'name'  => $season->getId()."_".$question->getId(),
     'label' => Mage::helper('your_helper_alias')->__(strip_tags($question->question)),
     'title' => Mage::helper('your_helper_alias')->__(strip_tags($question->question)),
     'class' => 'season-questions '.$season->getId(),
     'values' => $options,
     'value' => ''
 ));
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I tried strip_tags as a plan B which works fine, but the client wanted the ability to make the text bold and etc through a rich text field. So, is there a way to render html properly or do I just have to strip the tags?

Comment: you can put 'style' => 'somestyles' or define some css for defined class